# Customize uiswitch image properly?

Tags: ios, xcode, customization, uiswitch

I have an UISwitch in my iOS 6 app, that's on and off image is customised.

```
self.testSwitch.onImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"on"]; 
self.testSwitch.offImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"off"];
```

I use 77 points wide and 22 points tall image for this purpose (154x44 in retina), as it is stated in the documentation. But my image does not fit to my uiswitch, it seems ugly, the default style hides my one, like on the attached image.

[image]

What should I set to make it work in a proper way?

Comment: Try this at for once :- https://github.com/twotoasters/TTSwitch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't have an Appearance API for `UISwitch`. You can set a tint color property (`onTintColor`). But that's not what you want, I guess. The problem about customizing UISwitch is that there's the opportunity that Apple will reject your app.

But there are some APIs for a custom switch such as `RCSwitch`(https://github.com/robertchin/rcswitch) or `TTSwitch`. A good tutorial and example of how to use  `RCSwitch` can be found here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23424/photoshop-for-developers-creating-a-custom-uiswitch.

Comment: It has from IOS6!http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. But it's only for iOS 6. Using the libraries will make it compatible for older versions.

Comment: Thanks, kind from you. Anyway I don't need older versions in my project

Comment: So it looks like you also want to change the thumb look? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, as my book says thumb must be included in the custom image

Comment: I think that the thumb graphic that's generated by the system covers the on/off images which is in the back, like the TTSwitch library: https://raw.github.com/twotoasters/TTSwitch/master/Resources/switch_layers.png So think that the track layer there equals your on/off image.

Comment: FYI, iOS-6 adoption is > 92% (and climbing.)

Answer (score 6):

Here is [code from my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch25.html#_uiswitch). This is not exactly what you want to do, but it shows the technique and will get you started! Notice that I'm using 79 by 27 (not sure where you got your numbers from):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(79,27), NO, 0);
[[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
UIBezierPath* p = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0,0,79,27)];
[p fill];
NSMutableParagraphStyle* para = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
para.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
NSAttributedString* att =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"YES" attributes:
        @{
            NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Bold" size:16],
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:para
        }];
[att drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,5,79,22)];
UIImage* im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
self.sw2.onImage = im;
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It is from IOS6 programming CookBook, page 113

Comment: Yes, @giuseppe, they took this feature away again in iOS 7! So that code is iOS 6 _only_. This is really infuriating.

Comment: Yes this doesn't work in iOS 7 so don't waste your time changing the UISwitch look to that of another image. It sucks to be honest..